# Should I delete my Dumb question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, deletion

I read a post here recently (sorry I can't find it), where the issue of a high increase in low quality questions was brought to our attention.  I have a final coming shortly, so there is a question I would like to ask (graduate measure theory) but I don't really think its beneficial to everyone.  Would it be best to ask this and delete it afterward, or should such questions even be asked.  Just to establish what I consider a "dumb question", I would like to ask why the intersection of monotone classes that contain an algebra is still a monotone class.

Comment: If you're posting to meta out of concern that your question might be below community standards, you're probably not asking the type of dumb questions people are complaining about.

Answer (score 11):

You can only delete your question if it has no upvoted answers. If it has a valid non-upvoted answer and you delete the question then you will find yourself under a bit of a microscope. So no, you should not do that. The number of low-quality questions sitting around is an issue, but not *nearly* as big an issue as the rate at which they come in. Do not take this as discouraging you from asking your question. Please *do* ask it. If you ask it well, no one will complain.

Comment: I suppose most of "these" types of questions are also things like, "Please compute such and such", so I guess I'll just ask my question now.... eeeek.

Comment: @Squirtle ask your question. If you show research effort, and are clear, it is a good question. That post about low quality questions does not apply to math questions that meet those standards.